# How do I fill a selection using a defined pattern with photoshop type library?

Tags: .net, scripting, photoshop, fill, typelib

I'm trying to fill an image with a pattern I've defined previously.

```
Photoshop.Document document = new Photoshop.Document();
document.Selection.Fill(What goes here?);
```

I've been searching the net all over but haven't found any examples on how to use it properly.
The documentation shows me I need to provide:

- An object representing the FillType (which I guess it's where I specify that's a pettern I want there)
- A ColorBlendMode (which displays me a System.Type.Missing message)
- Opacity (same missing message)
- PreserveTransparency (also tells me that type missing message).

What am I missing?

Thank you all.